# Check login always return to login fail page in laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

public function check_login(Request $request){

```
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password'=> $request->password])){
    $request->session()->regenerateToken();
    return redirect("/profile");
  }
  return back()->withErrors(['failed'=>'invalid email and password']);


}
```

Comment: did you save password as hashed password ?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if you hashed the password during account creation and try again. You may also try this:

```
auth()->attempt([...]);
```

instead of:

```
Auth::attempt([...]);
```